# Linq2Sql Nullable association

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql

In multi-language project I have the following DB structure in SQL2005:

table StringTable:

```
   itemID int PK,
   stringID int NOT NULL,
   stringValue nvarchar,
   languageId int
```

table Articles:

```
   articleID int PK,
   titleID int NOT NULL (FK to StringTable.stringID),
   descriptionID int NULL (FK to StringTable.stringID)
```

I have trouble mapping the Articles.descriptionID->StringTable.stringID association in Linq2Sql (using the designer).. is says : "The parent property cannot be nullable if the child is nullable"... which I understand... but in my case the descriptionID needs to be nullable.
Can anybody help me with this issue or propose a workaround (using L2Sql and C#), I'm open to minor DB structure modifications too if it helps the case.

ps. All I need is a Descriptions property for the Article object which contains the descriptions (in all languages) of the given article or NULL.

Comment: Can you post the DBML for your two tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same problem - solved by add the association to the other table.

Comment: Well in my case with the above schema it was not possible to make the association (none of the two fields were primary keys). But at the end you answer is correct, i remade the whole DB structure, and made the proper associations (no more MxN).